# I can't seem to access sub arrays in swiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

So here is the JSON

```
{
"city": {
"id": 4930956,
"name": "Boston",
"coord": {
  "lon": -71.059769,
  "lat": 42.358429
},
"country": "US",
"population": 0,
"sys": {
  "population": 0
}
},
"cod": "200",
"message": 0.0424,
"cnt": 39,
"list": [
{
  "dt": 1473476400,
  "main": {
    "temp": 76.33,
    "temp_min": 73.11,
    "temp_max": 76.33,
    "pressure": 1026.47,
    "sea_level": 1027.96,
    "grnd_level": 1026.47,
    "humidity": 73,
    "temp_kf": 1.79
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 500,
      "main": "Rain",
      "description": "light rain",
      "icon": "10n"
    }
  ],
  "clouds": {
    "all": 8
  },
  "wind": {
    "speed": 7.29,
    "deg": 300.501
  },
```

Here is my Controller where I go grab the data......

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var amConnected: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var weatherTable: UITableView!
var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]()
var swiftyJsonVar: JSON?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.doSomethingNotification(_:)), name: "ReachabilityChangedNotification", object: nil)

    let openWMAPI = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?q=Boston,Ma&APPID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&units=imperial"

    Alamofire.request(.GET,openWMAPI).responseJSON{
        (responseData) -> Void in
        print(responseData)
        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

               self.weatherTable.reloadData()

        }
        .responseString{ response in
            //print(response.data.value)
           // print(response.result.value)
            //print(response.result.error)
            //eprint("inhere");

    }

    weatherTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    weatherTable.estimatedRowHeight = 140
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

In my table loop it is now saying that the jsonArray is nil and failing.
I'm unsure as to what I'm doing wrong at this point.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = weatherTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("theCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel
    print("inhere")


    if((swiftyJsonVar) != nil){
    if let jsonArray = self.swiftyJsonVar["list"].array {
        var temp = jsonArray[indexPath.row]["main"]["temp"].float
        var rdate = jsonArray[indexPath.row]["dt_txt"].string
        print(temp)
    }else{
        print("test")
    }
    }


    label1.text = "TEST"

    return cell
}
```

OVerall I'm just not sure how to dig down into the next level of the JSON.

Comment: Labels with tags on table view cells are pretty old-fashioned stuff. Design the cell in Interface Builder as custom cell with `IBOutlet`s. PS: Use always the dynamic passed `UITableView` instance in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` unless you really know why you need a static one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to the elements inside an JSON array in SwiftyJSON using consecutive subscripts, if we have the following JSON for example:

```
var json: JSON =  ["name": "Jack", "age": 25, 
                   "list": ["a", "b", "c", ["what": "this"]]]
```

Then you can access to the four element of the subarray `list`contained in the main array in the following way for example:

```
json["list"][3]["what"] // this
```

Or you can define a path like this `let path = ["list",3,"what"]` and then call it in this way:

```
json[path] // this
```

With the above explained let's introduce it with your JSON file to list the elements inside the array `weather`:

```
if let jsonArray = json["list"].array {

   // get the weather array
   if let weatherArray = jsonArray[0]["weather"].array {

       // iterate over the elements of the weather array
       for index in 0..<weatherArray.count {

           // and then access to the elements inside the weather array using optional getters.
           if let id = weatherArray[index]["id"].int, let main = weatherArray[index]["main"].string {
                print("Id: \(id)")
                print("Main: \(main)")
           }
       }
   }
}
```

And you should see in the console:

```
Id: 800
Main: Clear
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Victor thanks for the update. I updated my answer...seems like I'm further from the solution now. I'm getting an Exec error as explained above in my new updated post.

Comment: I know this has something to do with the sync of the data and variable but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Comment: @BostonMacOSX You're reloading the table view outside the request of Alamofire, and this is wrong because Alamofire make the request async. You need to put the call to reloadData  inside the request of Alamofire once the request it finished and it's successful.

Comment: I thought it was something like that...even when I put the reload table in the alamofire it would still fire off the table create before and error out I had to wrap the array work in a check to see if the swiftyJSON variable existed then it seemed not to error out. I thought the "if let" wouldl have taken care of this but it didn't. I had to wrap it in the if statement....getting closer to what I want...thanks for all th help

Comment: @BostonMacOSX I don't understand very well what you are telling me, but if the answer solve your question please can you accept it it help someone else?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not averse to it, try using AlamofireObjectMapper instead of SwiftyJson

1) If you are going to change the name of the json keys very often, and are going to do a lot of enum transformations try :

[AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper)

2) If the names are going to be the same, with minimal transformations, directly use :
[AlamofireJsonToObjects](https://github.com/evermeer/AlamofireJsonToObjects)

Both of these cases, create model classes for your json object. If you have an array - you can define a var as an array
if it is an object or an array of objects - you can then create another model class which is again Mappable and then define such an object var in the original model.

The above libraries will make your code extremely clean while extracting objects to json.